# How to change loadObjectList() item positions?

Tags: php, joomla

I tried to change the positions of the loadObjectList(). but it is not working. can anyone help me to solve this problem?

This is the code i used.

```
$catID = 8;
//echo $catID;
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$page_title = $doc->getTitle();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT title,alias FROM #__content WHERE catid = ".$catID);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList(); ?>
    <div>
    <?php foreach($articles as $article){
    $title = $article->title;
        if($title == $page_title){?>
            <h4><?php echo $article->title; ?></h4>
    <?php
        }else{ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $article->alias;?>"><h4><?php echo $article->title; ?></h4></a>
        <?php }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

what i want to do is, i want to display the page title as the first element of the list. Thats means if condition's item should display first.

can anyone helpe me?

Comment: What error do you get with the above code?

Comment: no errors. i can not order it. @emmanuel can you help me to order this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick dry solution is to add 2 foreach loops and first display the value if condition match and after the rest values.

```
<?php
    foreach($articles as $article){
        $title = $article->title;
        if($title == $page_title){
            echo '<h4>'. $article->title .'</h4>';
        }
    }
    foreach($articles as $rest_articles){
        $title = $rest_articles->title;
        if($title != $page_title){
            echo '<a href="'. $rest_articles->alias. '"><h4>'. $rest_articles->title .'</h4></a>';
        }
    }
?>
```

A better solution is to store values in a new array and display them afterwards.

Hope this helps

Comment: is this Bracket correct?. anyway thanks @emmanuel i got an idea from this.

Comment: It could work. For a better result you could sort values first in a temp array and display them afterwards.

Comment: i closed first foreach and then started rest one.

Comment: Just tweaked the closing brackets for you as one was incorrect and one was missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just had a double take here. Multiple `foreach` loops can be used, however are not required. Try the following:

```
<?php
    foreach($articles as $article) {
        $title = $article->title;
        $alias = $article->alias;

        if($title == $page_title) {
            echo '<h4>'. $title .'</h4>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<a href="'. $alias. '"><h4>'. $title .'</h4></a>';
        }
    }
?>
```